# How to check whether a file can be copied in SD card or not in case of Android Kitkat 4.2.2

Tags: android, copy-paste, android-4.4-kitkat

In a file manager I have to copy a file somewhere in external SD card, but in case of Android 4.2.2 write access is not permitted in external SD card. For that I wish to display a toast. One solution is to check the OS version and if it is Kitkat cancel further operation. But if a device that is rooted then external card can be written. So I don't want to use this approach. Is there any other way to check that file cannot be written in SD card?